# Конструкторы в C++

Tags: c++

Читал статью на MSDN и там был такой код:

```
#include <iostream>  
using namespace std;

class Contained1 {
public:
    Contained1() {
        cout << "Contained1 constructor." << endl;
    }
};

class Contained2 {
public:
    Contained2() {
        cout << "Contained2 constructor." << endl;
    }
};

class Contained3 {
public:
    Contained3() {
        cout << "Contained3 constructor." << endl;
    }
};

class BaseContainer {
public:
    BaseContainer() {
        cout << "BaseContainer constructor." << endl;
    }
private:
    Contained1 c1;
    Contained2 c2;
};

class DerivedContainer : public BaseContainer {
public:
    DerivedContainer() : BaseContainer() {
        cout << "DerivedContainer constructor." << endl;
    }
private:
    Contained3 c3;
};

int main(void) 
{
    DerivedContainer dc;
}
```

Там было написано: `Сначала вызывается конструктор базового класса, затем инициализируются члены базового класса...`, но у меня выводит:

```
Contained1 constructor.
Contained2 constructor.
BaseContainer constructor.
Contained3 constructor.
DerivedContainer constructor.
```

Я не понимаю почему он сначала инициализирует члены базового класса, а потом выполняет конструктор

Comment: Дайте-ка ссылку на статью. Чтоб самим посмотреть, как там написано...

Comment: @Harry https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/s16xw1a8.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При вызове конструктора сначала произойдет инициализация его членов (либо значениями, которые вы указали явно, либо значениями по умалчанию, ну или мусором), а уже потом произойдет то, что вы прописали внутри фигурных скобок в конструкторе. Тобишь:

```
class BaseContainer {
public:
    BaseContainer() /*вот сдесь произойдет инициализация членов*/ {
        /*а вот сдесь уже все что вы описали в конструкторе*/
        cout << "BaseContainer constructor." << endl;
    }
private:
    Contained1 c1;
    Contained2 c2;
};
```

Когда вы делаете так:

```
BaseContainer alfa;
```

Вызывется конструктор `BaseContainer` по умолчанию, который сначала инициализирует члены класса, а потом уже выполнит все, что вы указали в фигурных скобках.

PS важно понимать, что ИНИЦИАЛИЗАЦИЯ это не присваивание, и происходит оно прежде, чем будет выполнена какая-либо инструкция в фигурных скобках. Тобишь, если совсем по простому, между вызовом конструктора и открытием фигурной скобки.

Comment: Получается MDSN наврал или я чего-то не понял?

Comment: @PoulShipilov почему наврал? Конструктор-то действительны вызывается перед тем, как будут инициализированы его члены. Просто нужно понимать последовательность, с которой это будет сделано.

Comment: А ну я понял, сам вызов конструктора инициализирует его члены, а зачем тогда писать, что после вызова конструктора инициализируются его члены

Comment: @PoulShipilov наверно потому, что члены инициализируются после того, как вы вызываете конструктор... Просто инициализация это процесс который происходит между вызовом конструктора и исполнением инструкций в фигурных скобках. Так что инициализация членов класса происходит после вызова конструктора, но до того, как будет открыта первая фигурная скобка.

Comment: Все я понял, спасибо большое

Answer (score 2):

Давайте разбираться. Итак, написано -

*Вызывает конструкторы базовых классов и членов в порядке объявления.*

Т.е. у вас сначала конструируется базовый класс - `BaseContainer`, потом конструктор члена `Contained3` (к счастью, члены у вас не являются производными, так что глубже копать не нужно). И только потом вызывается сам конструктор `DerivedContainer()`. И так для каждого класса.

`BaseContainer` своего базового класса не имеет, так что в порядке объявления вызываются только конструкторы членов -

```
Contained1
Contained2
```

а затем сам конструктор базового класса

```
BaseContainer
```

Затем, как уже мы говорили, вызовется конструктор

```
Contained3
```

и последним - самый "внешний" конструктор `DerivedContainer()`.

Итак,

```
Contained1
Contained2
BaseContainer
Contained3 
DerivedContainer
```

Все, как написано в MSDN...

Мне кажется, вы неверно прочли

*Вызывает конструкторы базовых классов и членов в порядке объявления.*

как

*Вызывает конструкторы базовых классов и членов базового класса в порядке объявления.* - т.е. что вызывается конструктор базового класса, а потом конструкторы членов базового же класса...

Answer (score 1):

Для любого класса порядок конструирования таков:

1. Конструктор базового класса (если есть базовый)
2. Конструкторы членов класса
3. Свой конструктор

Этот порядок действует и для вашего базового класса, поэтому сначала конструируются его члены, потом  вызывается конструктор базового, после конструктор члена этого класса, а потом конструктор данного класса, что вы и видите в результате...